# Query return result on Oracle but not SQL Server. Solution should be work for SQL Server and Oracle db

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I am unable to search the product with `[` special character if my application is connected with SQL Server, but its working fine for Oracle.

```
select * from product where product_code like '%DAY[%'
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server `[` is a wildcard character, that need to be escape it by [`ESCAPE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms179859.aspx) option.

So the following query will work in SQL Server:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product 
WHERE product_code LIKE '%DAY#[%' ESCAPE '#'
```

Comment: Thanks, but solution should be for both SQL and Oracle.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: that query results in "ORA-01424: missing or illegal character following the escape character" in Oracle because the escape character is only allowed in front of wildcard characters.